# How Would I Query ICANN Domain Lookup Information Through Windows Command CURL?

Tags: cmd.exe, curl, whois

I want to query ICANN domain lookup through Windows command (cmd.exe). I found the ICANN API https://opendata.icann.org/api/v2/console but after skimming through the documentation, I did not find anything about domain look ups.

I don't want to install any other application, and I hope there is a simple CURL I can execute to lookup the public contact information for a domain. If this is possible, could you include an example?

Comment: Do you have access to Linux subsystem or commands ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot No, just a Windows machine

Comment: Do you have `grep` & `whois` ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot I have what I stated in the question. Please if you don't have the answer stop asking for other programs, utilities or operating systems

Answer (score 1):

Source: ARIN (American Registry for Internet Numbers): Using Command-Line Interface (CLI) Clients with Whois

```
https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/rws/cli/
```

```
C:\Users\patrick>whois /?

Whois v1.21 - Domain information lookup
Copyright (C) 2005-2019 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Usage: whois [-v] domainname [whois.server]
 -v   Print whois information for referrals
 -nobanner
      Do not display the startup banner and copyright message.
```

```
C:\Users\patrick>whois superuser.com

Whois v1.21 - Domain information lookup
Copyright (C) 2005-2019 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Connecting to COM.whois-servers.net...

WHOIS Server: whois.corporatedomains.com
   Registrar URL: http://cscdbs.com
   Updated Date: 2022-08-17T04:32:05Z
   Creation Date: 1995-11-01T05:00:00Z
   Registry Expiry Date: 2024-02-02T11:59:59Z
   Registrar: CSC Corporate Domains, Inc.
   Registrar IANA ID: 299
   Registrar Abuse Contact Email: domainabuse@cscglobal.com
   Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: 8887802723
   Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
   Name Server: NS-1699.AWSDNS-20.CO.UK
   Name Server: NS-245.AWSDNS-30.COM
   Name Server: NS-CLOUD-D1.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
   Name Server: NS-CLOUD-D2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
   DNSSEC: unsigned
   URL of the ICANN Whois Inaccuracy Complaint Form: https://www.icann.org/wicf/
>>> Last update of whois database: 2023-05-04T15:34:39Z <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp

{much deletia}

The Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and
Registrars.

Connecting to whois.corporatedomains.com...

WHOIS Server: whois.corporatedomains.com
Registrar URL: www.cscprotectsbrands.com
Updated Date: 2022-08-17T00:32:08Z
Creation Date: 1995-11-01T00:00:00Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2024-02-02T11:59:59Z
Registrar: CSC CORPORATE DOMAINS, INC.
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 299
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: domainabuse@cscglobal.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.8887802723
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Registry Registrant ID:
Registrant Name: Domain Administrator
Registrant Organization: Stack Exchange, Inc.
Registrant Street: 110 William Street, 28th Floor
Registrant City: New York
Registrant State/Province: NY
Registrant Postal Code: 10038
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: +1.2122328280
Registrant Phone Ext:
Registrant Fax: +1.2122328280
Registrant Fax Ext:
Registrant Email: sysadmin-team@stackoverflow.com
Registry Admin ID:
Admin Name: Domain Administrator
Admin Organization: Stack Exchange, Inc.
Admin Street: 110 William Street, 28th Floor
Admin City: New York
Admin State/Province: NY
Admin Postal Code: 10038
Admin Country: US
Admin Phone: +1.2122328280
Admin Phone Ext:
Admin Fax: +1.2122328280
Admin Fax Ext:
Admin Email: sysadmin-team@stackoverflow.com
Registry Tech ID:
Tech Name: Domain Administrator
Tech Organization: Stack Exchange, Inc.
Tech Street: 110 William Street, 28th Floor
Tech City: New York
Tech State/Province: NY
Tech Postal Code: 10038
Tech Country: US
Tech Phone: +1.2122328280
Tech Phone Ext:
Tech Fax: +1.2122328280
Tech Fax Ext:
Tech Email: sysadmin-team@stackoverflow.com
Name Server: ns-1699.awsdns-20.co.uk
Name Server: ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com
Name Server: ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
Name Server: ns-245.awsdns-30.com
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2022-08-17T00:32:08Z <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp

{much deletia}

Domain Name: superuser.com
Registry Domain ID: 1650980_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.corporatedomains.com
Registrar URL: www.cscprotectsbrands.com
Updated Date: 2022-08-17T00:32:08Z
Creation Date: 1995-11-01T00:00:00Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2024-02-02T11:59:59Z
Registrar: CSC CORPORATE DOMAINS, INC.
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 299
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: domainabuse@cscglobal.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.8887802723
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Registry Registrant ID:
Registrant Name: Domain Administrator
Registrant Organization: Stack Exchange, Inc.
Registrant Street: 110 William Street, 28th Floor
Registrant City: New York
Registrant State/Province: NY
Registrant Postal Code: 10038
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: +1.2122328280
Registrant Phone Ext:
Registrant Fax: +1.2122328280
Registrant Fax Ext:
Registrant Email: sysadmin-team@stackoverflow.com
Registry Admin ID:
Admin Name: Domain Administrator
Admin Organization: Stack Exchange, Inc.
Admin Street: 110 William Street, 28th Floor
Admin City: New York
Admin State/Province: NY
Admin Postal Code: 10038
Admin Country: US
Admin Phone: +1.2122328280
Admin Phone Ext:
Admin Fax: +1.2122328280
Admin Fax Ext:
Admin Email: sysadmin-team@stackoverflow.com
Registry Tech ID:
Tech Name: Domain Administrator
Tech Organization: Stack Exchange, Inc.
Tech Street: 110 William Street, 28th Floor
Tech City: New York
Tech State/Province: NY
Tech Postal Code: 10038
Tech Country: US
Tech Phone: +1.2122328280
Tech Phone Ext:
Tech Fax: +1.2122328280
Tech Fax Ext:
Tech Email: sysadmin-team@stackoverflow.com
Name Server: ns-1699.awsdns-20.co.uk
Name Server: ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com
Name Server: ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
Name Server: ns-245.awsdns-30.com
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2022-08-17T00:32:08Z <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp

{much deletia}
```